# Remove negatively correlated variables in linear regression

Tags: correlation, feature-selection, model-selection, regression-strategies

I am trying to fit a linear regression for my model. There are 9 predictors X1,X2,............,X9.

I tried to look at the correlation of each of these with Y, the dependent variable. Should I remove the X variable which is negatively or not very less correlation with Y?

I know there might not be a specific answer to this and it is highly dependent on my situation, but any help that gives me a general idea is really welcome.

Comment: What is your intuition for why you would do such a thing?

Comment: Being negatively correlated is a relevant information: what would happen if the underlying model were $y=-2x$ ?

Comment: Got it.My mistake. So we remove the variables which are not correlated, since they cannot predict a change in our Y to the extent we want

Comment: No. It might be that $\text{corr}(x_1,y)=0$, $\text{corr}(x_1,y)=0$ but $\text{corr}(x_1+\beta x_2,y) \neq 0$ for some $\beta$. In a multiple regression setting, checking pairwise correlations of the regressand and one of the regressors is not the best idea for variable selection.

Comment: If you are interested in variable selection, check out the posts tagged [`feature-selection`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-selection), [`model-selection`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-selection), [`regression-strategies`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regression-strategies).